# UISearchBar button

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I was working on the `UISearchBar` in Xcode and while running the app, this button appeared in the search text field and it's still there since.

Did anybody face this problem before? How to delete this button.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unselect the `Shows Search Results Button` attribute in Attributes Inspector.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Untick the box shows search results button. it will hide

[image]